# Feature Union with Pandas: Properly Selecting Columns?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a df file likeso:

`+------------+----------------------+---------+--+--+
| number_col | text_col             | outcome |  |  |
+------------+----------------------+---------+--+--+
| 42         | Here isa string      | 1       |  |  |
+------------+----------------------+---------+--+--+
| 52         | And here is a string | 0       |  |  |
+------------+----------------------+---------+--+--+`

I am trying to use an SVM  to predict `outcome`, with a feature union of `text_col` being transformed with a vectorizer and `number-col` being transformed by standardizing scalar. Here is my code ([drawing on this example):](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py)

```
class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]

a = Pipeline([
        ('union', FeatureUnion(
            transformer_list=[
                # Pipeline for vectorizing text
                ('subject', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', ItemSelector(key='text_col')),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=50)),
                ])),
                # Pipeline for standardizing number_col
                ('body_bow', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', ItemSelector(key='number_col')),
                    ('std', StandardScaler()),
                ])),
            ]
        )),
        # Use a SVC classifier on the combined features
        ('svc', SVC()),
    ])

    a.fit(df, df['outcome'])
```

I get `KeyError: 'text_col'` because evidently `transform` is dropping off the other columns? How would I make my code work so that I vectorize `text_col` but don't lop off `number_col`?

Comment: No, transform of ItemSelector doesnt drop off other columns. In FeatureUnion, same data (df in this case) will sent parallely to all the internal transformers.

Comment: I am not getting any error on duplicating this code on my machine. Please add more details like scikit-learn version and complete code and stack trace of error.